# jsoup nodes vs elements pull values

Tags: android, jsoup

```
<div class="eight columns">
<form method="post" action="http://www.way2franchise.com/search/filter_franchise">

<div style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:20px;">

<select name="industry" id="industry" class="searchBoxSel" title="Select Industry">

<option value="candies_and_confectioneries">Candies and Confectioneries</option>
<option value="childrens_services"> Children's Services</option>
<option value="sports_and_recreatio">Sports &amp; Recreation</option>
<option value="staffing_franchises">Staffing Franchises</option>
```

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<select name="investment" id="investment" class="searchBoxSel" title="Select     Investment">

<option value="">Select Investment</option>
<option value="2500000">Under Rs.2,500,000</option>
<option value="10000000">Under Rs.10,000,000</option>
<option value="50000000">Under Rs.50,000,000</option>
</select>
</div>


<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<select class="searchBoxSel" title="Select State" id="state" name="state">
<option value="">Select State</option>
<option value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands">Andaman and Nicobar</option>
<option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value="Arunachal Pradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>

</select>
</div>
</form></div>

    Here, I need to get the option value pair in an array.While testing the code out i executed the following code:

     String q=doc.select("eight columns").text();
     System.out.println(q);
```

Using Jsoup selector syntax, i am supposed to get the entire code into the string 'q'.
But i am getting a null value instead (logcat). How to?

Also doc.select("h3.r > a> p >h1") means? I didn't find any good tutorials on this.Even the jsoup cookbook doesn't explain these concepts in a broader aspect.

I went through the DOM concept,as in , parent,sibling concepts.There i read concepts about nodes. So While writing something as 
Elements e=doc. .... or Element e=doc

Can we substitute that creating nodes instead?is this feasible ,recommended?

I am barely able to scape values in string from html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get class "eight columns" you can use getElementsByClass() example:

```
Elements eightcolumns = doc.getElementsByClass("eight columns");
            String str = eightcolumns.first().text();
```

or select() :

```
 Elements eightcolumns = doc.select("div.eight columns");
            String str = eightcolumns.first().text();
```

Comment: Thank you @user1888162.But that's not actualy where my doubt is.If i am not using elements , how can i achieve the same using nodes?Also what does it doc.select("h3.r > a> p >h1") means?I tried it, but i still have bugs in grasping the concept.

Comment: Could me tell me how to get options value in an array?